# Android parsing json array with different content types

Tags: android, json

I have following json array:

```
key_highlights: [
  {
    feature_id: "",
    name: "body_type",
    display_name: "Body Type",
    data_type: "text",
    data_values: [
       "Sedan"
    ]
  },
  {
    feature_id: "",
    name: "exterior_color",
    display_name: "Exterior Color",
    data_type: "color",
    data_values: [
      {
         hexcode: "#ffffff",
         actual: "Teak Brown",
         normalized: "other"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    feature_id: "",
    name: "transmission_type",
    display_name: "Transmission Type",
    data_type: "text",
    data_values: [
        1,
        2
    ]
  }
}]
```

As given in the json, the data_values array can have content of different type. It can be array of json object, integer or string. I am not getting how do I parse the data_values array.

Comment: Ask the guys that sent you that JSON ... ?

Comment: Who creates a JSON like that.

Comment: You need to check the "data_type" key and based on that parse the "data_values". Eg : If it is "color", parse the encoded color json object otherwise parse it as string array.

Comment: @HarishSridharan I am already using data_type key. This is just dummy. Even with "data_type"->  text, array of json objects may be returned by the server.

Comment: @Nitish check my answer.

Comment: Check your `JSON` is valid or not [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

Comment: @MD This is dummy json structure. Only thing I missed is I forgot to enclose it inside an json object and keys are not within double quotes

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment in question that "data_type" have no relation to type of "data_values", its seems to be a very bad design. I would suggest you to change the JSON hierarchy but if you are still want to go ahead with the given JSON, use the following code:

```
Object dataValues = jsonObject.opt("data_values");

if(dataValues instanceof String[]) {

String[] sDataValues = (String[]) dataValues;

}
else if(dataValues instanceof int[]) {

int[] iDataValues = (int[]) dataValues;

}
else if(dataValues instanceof JSONArray) {

JSONArray jArrayDataValues = (JSONArray) dataValues;

}
```